# In SDL Tridion 2011, how can I process metadata on an item using the Core Service?

Tags: tridion

I'm using the Core Service to read Keyword information in SDL Tridion 2011. How can I process any metadata on the items I'm reading? I can see a `Metadata` property that contains a string of XML, and a `MetadataSchema` property that represents a link to a Schema. Should I deal directly with the XML, or is there a way to do something more like the `ItemFields` processing in the TOM.Net?

What if I want to add metadata to an item that doesn't already have any set?

Comment: I think this question applies to changing the content/metadata of any item type. If you agree, do you mind changing it a bit to broaden the scope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to provide your own code to parse and modify that XML, based on the associated Schema. I wrote a small `Fields` class to do the heavy lifting, which you can find here: https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata

Comment: Looks like a very useful solution. It should really simply metadata processing.