# Using SDL Tridion 2011 Core Service to create Components programatically

Tags: tridion

I have seen some of the questions/answers related to this topic here, however still I am not getting the suggestion which I want.  So I am posting my question again here, and I would be thankful for your valuable time and answers.

I would like to create “Component, Page, SG, Publication, Folders “ via programmatically in SDL Tridion Content Manager, and later on, I would like to add programmatically created components in Page and attach CT,PT for that page, and finally would like to publish the page programmatically.

I have done these all the activities in SDL Tridion 2009 using TOM API (Interop DLL's), and I tried these activities in SDL Tridion 2011 using TOM.Net API. It was not working and later on I came to know that, TOM.Net API will not support these kinds of works and it is specifically only for Templates and Event System. And finally I came to know I have to go for Core services to do these kinds of stuffs.

**My Questions:**

1. When I create console application to create component programmatically using core service, what are the DLL’s I have to add as reference?
2. Earlier, I have created the exe and ran in the TCM server, the exe created all the stuffs, can I used the same approach using core services too? Will it work?
3. Is BC still available or Core Service replaced BC? (BC-Business Connector)
4. Can anyone send some code snippet to create Component/Page (complete class file will be helpful to understand better)

Comment: The Core Service is the Business Connector 2.0. So when we're referring to the Business Connector being deprecated, it's specifically the original BC and API, pre-SDL Tridion 2011. See the [SDL material](http://www.sdl.com/products/tridion/business-connector.html) and a nice [overview from Bart Koopman on the SDL Tridion 2011 integration points](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/tackleintegrations.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How can i use engine object in my console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473513/how-can-i-use-engine-object-in-my-console-application/11501818)

From a console application you should use the Core Service. I wrote a small example using the Core Service to search for items in the content manager.

```
Console.WriteLine("FullTextQuery:");

var fullTextQuery = Console.ReadLine();

if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fullTextQuery) || fullTextQuery.Equals(":q", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    break;
}

Console.WriteLine("SearchIn IdRef:");

var searchInIdRef = Console.ReadLine();

var queryData = new SearchQueryData
                    {
                        FullTextQuery = fullTextQuery,
                        SearchIn = new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData
                                        {
                                            IdRef = searchInIdRef
                                        }
                    };

var results = coreServiceClient.GetSearchResults(queryData);
results.ToList().ForEach(result => Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", result.Title, result.Id));
```

Add a reference to Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client to your Visual Studio Project.

Code of the Core Service Client Provider:

```
public interface ICoreServiceProvider
{
    CoreServiceClient GetCoreServiceClient();
}

public class CoreServiceDefaultProvider : ICoreServiceProvider
{
    private CoreServiceClient _client;

    public CoreServiceClient GetCoreServiceClient()
    {
        return _client ?? (_client = new CoreServiceClient());
    }
}
```

And the client itself:

```
public class CoreServiceClient : IDisposable
{
    public SessionAwareCoreServiceClient ProxyClient;

    private const string DefaultEndpointName = "netTcp_2011";

    public CoreServiceClient(string endPointName)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(endPointName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("endPointName", "EndPointName is not specified.");
        }

        ProxyClient = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(endPointName);
    }

    public CoreServiceClient() : this(DefaultEndpointName) { }

    public string GetApiVersionNumber()
    {
        return ProxyClient.GetApiVersion();
    }

    public IdentifiableObjectData[] GetSearchResults(SearchQueryData filter)
    {
        return ProxyClient.GetSearchResults(filter);
    }

    public IdentifiableObjectData Read(string id)
    {
        return ProxyClient.Read(id, new ReadOptions());
    }

    public ApplicationData ReadApplicationData(string subjectId, string applicationId)
    {
        return ProxyClient.ReadApplicationData(subjectId, applicationId);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (ProxyClient.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
        {
            ProxyClient.Abort();
        }
        else
        {
            ProxyClient.Close();
        } 
    }
}
```

When you want to perform CRUD actions through the core service you can implement the following methods in the client:

```
public IdentifiableObjectData CreateItem(IdentifiableObjectData data)
{
    data = ProxyClient.Create(data, new ReadOptions());
    return data;
}

public IdentifiableObjectData UpdateItem(IdentifiableObjectData data)
{
    data = ProxyClient.Update(data, new ReadOptions());
    return data;
}

public IdentifiableObjectData ReadItem(string id)
{
    return ProxyClient.Read(id, new ReadOptions());
}
```

To construct a data object of e.g. a Component you can implement a Component Builder class that implements a create method that does this for you:

```
public ComponentData Create(string folderUri, string title, string content)
{
    var data = new ComponentData()
                    {
                        Id = "tcm:0-0-0",
                        Title = title,
                        Content = content,
                        LocationInfo = new LocationInfo()
                    };

    data.LocationInfo.OrganizationalItem = new LinkToOrganizationalItemData
    {
        IdRef = folderUri
    };

using (CoreServiceClient client = provider.GetCoreServiceClient())
{
    data = (ComponentData)client.CreateItem(data);
}

    return data;
}
```

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Using CoreServiceClient name for client would cause ambiguous naming error, while trying (using (CoreServiceClient client = provider.GetCoreServiceClient())) any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 6):

1. You will only need to reference Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll. You **may** want to reference Tridion.Common.dll to get access to some helpful classes such as `TcmUri`, but it is not needed.
2. You client program will make an explicit connection with the core service on a machine that you specify. If done properly, you can run the client both on the same machine as the Tridion Content Manager or on a different machine.
3. The Business Connector is still available, but has been superseded by the Core Service.
4. Have a look at these links:

[Updating Components using the Core Service in SDL Tridion 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069726/updating-components-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011/10073979#10073979)

[In SDL Tridion 2011, how can I process metadata on an item using the Core Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379562/in-sdl-tridion-2011-how-can-i-process-metadata-on-an-item-using-the-core-servic/9379653#9379653)

And the standard documentation on the topic [connecting to the Core Service from .NET](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_B49EC308F06D48E19230A2EC6070E14E).

If you need more help with the code, I suggest you show us the code you've already written and explain what isn't working.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have gone throught he coreservice API, and i see all the building blocks related classes are available in (Tridion.contentmanager.data.dll) and i could not find this dll in the Tridion server. also i couldnt find Tridion.contentmanger.coreservice.client dll also. but i could locate Tridion.cotentmanager.coreservice.dll. And how to get the coreservice session to proceed with creating components and etc?

Comment: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll was added in Tridion 2011 SP1. If you're still on Tridion 2011 GA, you'll have to add a service reference in Visual Studio and let that generate the necessary client-side code for you. You should ** not** add any other DLLs than the ones I mentioned (or better yet: that are mentioned in the documentation) to your client. There are plenty of example already on how to create a CoreServiceSession; I suggest you google for it and read some articles from Ryan Durkin, Robert Curlette or one of the other experts.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks a lot, I was able to create folder using coreservice.
 I am using Tridion 2011 GA, I am able to add service reference (http://servername/webservice/coreservice.svc) in my console application from the Tridion server.
And I tried to add the same reference from my local client desktop, I am not able to add.
And when I run the exe from the server, it created the folder, how to run the same exe from client machine?

Comment: Check you app.config for references to localhost. Check that you can access the .svc from a browser window. You might also consider posting that problem separately with a [wcf] category, since it has nothing to do with Tridion and most of the Tridion experts are not WCF experts (yet).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I am able to add the service reference in my local machine after adding the below node in my app.config "<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>"

Comment: Good one, I indeed had to configure a proxy once too and completely forgot about it. Proxies are a thing of evil. :-/

Answer (score 4):

I will try to answer your questions:

1. You have to reference Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client and add some stuff to app.config. It's described [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?c=t&action=html&resource=publist_home.html#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&lang=&action=search&query=Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1338460433722&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_B49EC308F06D48E19230A2EC6070E14E&pubid=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&publang=en-US&resource=c3817be3-6322-460f-a776-095945670d97.xml&docid=task_B49EC308F06D48E19230A2EC6070E14E&filename=GettingTheDotNETClientUpAndRunning.xml&query=Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client&scope=&tid=b0d2502a-9dfd-4b76-843b-d4e52c6f0919&inner_id=&addHistory=true)
2. It will work from CM server, as well as from any other machine, provided it can access CoreService
3. CoreService is replacement for BC. BC is deprecated and will be dropped soon
4. You will get all the basic info from [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1338460671748&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_25F3C706E3A945A89870045A9ECAC139&query=&scope=&filename=RetrievingItems.xml&docid=concept_25F3C706E3A945A89870045A9ECAC139&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=).

This should be enough for you to start. If you will have specific problems - post them as a seperate questions.